# JavaScript compare input range.value with input range.max

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a plus and a minus button to work together with a slider (input type="range").
However it doesn't work as I expect it to. I created a fiddle:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);

function eventWindowLoaded() {
  var buttonMinusRef = document.getElementById("buttonMinus");
  var buttonPlusRef = document.getElementById("buttonPlus");
  var brushSizeRef = document.getElementById("brushSize");

  buttonMinusRef.addEventListener("click", incrementBrushSize, false);
  buttonPlusRef.addEventListener("click", incrementBrushSize, false);

  function incrementBrushSize() {
    if (this.id === "buttonPlus") {
      /* Plus Button was clicked. */
      if (brushSizeRef.value < brushSizeRef.max) {
        brushSizeRef.value++;
        drawSize = brushSizeRef.value;
        console.log("it works");
      } else {
        console.log("it doesn't work");
      }
    } else {
      /* Minus Button was clicked. */
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Brush size: <span id="currentSize"></span>
  </p>
  <button id="buttonMinus">-</button>
  <input type="range" id="brushSize" min="1" max="140" value="20" />
  <button id="buttonPlus">+</button>
  <br />
</body>

</html>
```

My idea for this code is: the user clicks either plus or minus button. If the plus button is clicked the slider value is increased by one (minus decreases by one.)
I only want the plus button to do anything if the current .value is less than .max (and the other way around for the minus button.)
I want to use .min, .max and .value to avoid hardcoding values into the comparisons.

What happens: it only seems to work when the slider is within the 130-something to 150-something range. I have no idea why.

Answer (score -1):

Change :

```
 if (brushSizeRef.value < brushSizeRef.max) {
```

To :

```
 if (brushSizeRef.value < parseInt(brushSizeRef.max)) {
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
          <p>Brush size: <span id="currentSize"></span>
          </p>
          <button id="buttonMinus">-</button>
          <input type="range" id="brushSize" min="1" max="140" value="20" />
          <button id="buttonPlus">+</button>
          <br />
       
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);
            function eventWindowLoaded() {
              var buttonMinusRef = document.getElementById("buttonMinus");
              var buttonPlusRef = document.getElementById("buttonPlus");
              var brushSizeRef = document.getElementById("brushSize");

              buttonMinusRef.addEventListener("click", incrementBrushSize, false);
              buttonPlusRef.addEventListener("click", incrementBrushSize, false);

              function incrementBrushSize() {
                if (this.id == "buttonPlus") {
                  /* Plus Button was clicked. */
                  if (brushSizeRef.value < parseInt(brushSizeRef.max)) {
                    brushSizeRef.value++;
                    drawSize = brushSizeRef.value;
                    console.log("it works");
                  } else {
                    console.log("it doesn't work");
                  }
                } else {
                  /* Minus Button was clicked. */
                }
              }
           }
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

parseInt(brushSizeRef.value). The type of brush.min , brush.max, brush.value is string this is the reason it is not working.

Comment: Is it possible to find out what data type a variable has (without using typeof)? Maybe by using the console?

Comment: isNAN is one thing it will tell whether it is a number or not